# Changing media queries from min-width to use max-width to avoid overriding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Rather than having one huge responsive.css files. I am including the media queries in the same stylsheet to keep everything together, for example i have wizard.css file, with:

```
 span.crumbsTxt {
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1.25em;
 }
```

Then at the bottom of the same wizard.css file, i have:

```
    /* col-sm - Small tablets */
    @media (min-width: 768px){
         span.crumbsTxt {
         font-size: 14px;
       }
    }
```

The issue i am having is that all my styles from the media queries are overriding my original styles, even when it doesn't hit the small screen media query.

So in this example i am on a large screen, but for some reason its using all my styles from the media query!

I don't want to use !important, but don't understand why its doing this as it's breaking my whole site!

Thanks

EDIT:
Is my media query setup wrong then - what needs to change?

Are my media queries wrong then, what needs to change to avoid my issues? :-

```
 /* col-xs - mobile screens */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

 /* col-sm - Small tablets */
 @media (min-width: 768px) {}

 /* col-md - Medium screens */
 @media (min-width: 992px) {}

 /* col-lg - Large Desktop screens */
 @media (min-width: 1250px) {}
```

Seems that my bootstrap.min.css uses min width as well. Any ideas on how i could change the above media queries to solve the overriding issue i am having?

SOLUTION:

Would this be better suited - normal css first then order media queries largest first down to smallest and use max-width instead of min-width? The only thing im not sure on is the screen size values i have added - are these ok?

```
 Normal css first

 /* col-lg - Large Desktop screens */
 @media (max-width: 1824px) {}

 /* col-md - Medium screens */
 @media (max-width: 1250px) {}

 /* col-sm - Small tablets */
 @media (max-width: 992px) {}

 /* col-xs - mobile screens */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}
```

Comment: [**Logic in Media Queries**](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your max- vs min-width mixed up.

`max-width` applies anywhere under the width set and `min-width` applies anywhere above

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    span.crumbsTxt {
     font-size: 14px;
   }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/dhz6mxb3/)**

**EDIT:**
You have two options for ordering your media queries:
Option one (as you note above), order them largest to smallest as it will always apply the most recently declared styles first.
Second, make the media queries exclusive blocks:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px){
    span.crumbsTxt {
     font-size: 14px;
   }
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/dhz6mxb3/4/)**

Lets walk through your media-queries as an example:
(Lets assume we are on a screen size of 1000px)

```
 @media (max-width: 1824px) {} /* this media query will apply because the screen is less than 1824px */

 @media (max-width: 1250px) {} /* this media query will then apply (on-top-of the first media query) */

 @media (max-width: 992px) {} /* this media query will not apply because the screen size is greater than 992px */

 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}  /* this media query will not apply because the screen size is greater than 767px */
```

If you want to avoid that cascading effect, you could modify your media queries like this:

```
 @media (max-width: 1824px) and (min-width: 1251px) {} 
 @media (max-width: 1250px) and (min-width: 993px) {} 
 @media (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 768px) {} 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}
```

*note, with this exclusive version, the order of the media queries is irrelevant

Comment: try refresh the page mate i have edited? that ok on the solution bit compared to what i had originally?

Comment: I addressed your additional question in my answer above

Comment: It seems better to go with your version to avoid that cascading effect you mention as im having to override styles all the time. Do you think this is the better option? Sorry for the questions as im fairly new to this!

Comment: Yes, that is the option I use myself... the biggest advantage is that you dont need to ensure you override styles all the time (ex. if your large media query adds/changes 100 lines of CSS, your medium media query can change only 1 without getting stuck with all the changes the large media query made) -- it sort of encapsulates the individual media queries rather than letting them be additive

Comment: thats been a great help and solved a big head ache for me, nicely explained as well, thank you! :-)

Comment: One other quick question my bootstrap.min.css uses the very first set of media queries i posted in my original question above, using min-width etc for the col-lg etc layouts, should i edit this file and add in your recommended changes, or will it not matter?

Comment: I would leave their media queries alone because they have thought through the cascading and tested the framework that way. You can write yours the way we discussed above.

Comment: will do, i have added your recommended media queries and it works a treat! nice one!